# Porting Binder IPC to Linux

Tags: linux, ipc

Android provides a device driver based IPC mechanism called Binder. I see it as one of the staging drivers in Linux. Although I can have a linux kernel running with this device driver, if I want to use it for IPC between applications in my desktop Linux, what other steps do I need to complete ?

Any reference would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[Binders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenBinder) are an Android addition to the Linux kernel. They don't exist outside Android in currently deployed kernels. They've been merged into the mainline kernel (the “real” Linux kernel, not the Android one) [in Linux 3.19](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.19#head-fa49268d45ce9bae2e47c5a75ef0333947fa18a6), in February 2015.

If you don't mind that your application won't run on desktop distributions until a couple of years from now, you can use binders.

If you want your application to run now, use another IPC mechanism. Linux doesn't lack IPC mechanisms — you can use pipes, sockets, shared memory, …

Comment: Ok .. I was just asking for learning purposes ..

Comment: But still .. is there any documentation you know of that tells what would need to be done in userspace for instance if Binder IPC was to be used in Desktop Linux .. ?

Comment: @Jake, take a look at the **resources** section of this wiki page http://elinux.org/Android_Binder. There is some great information there about binder. Cheers.

Comment: Maybe de closest to Android binder would be DBUS.  Implementing serious IPC on top of those primitives is rather complicated.